# Python list and sklearn HashingVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a a nested python list in the following format

```
npes = [['a','b'], ['d','e'],['f','g']]
```

I need to vectorizer this list using HashingVectorizer() however I cant understand how I should process this list using vectorizer.fit_transform

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
Xc = vectorizer.fit_transform(npes)
```

The above gives the following error

```
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know about the sklearn HashingVectorizer, but the function `lower` turns a capital at the beginning of a string into a lowercase letter. That means your script interprets the elements of `npes` as `strings`, but instead they are `lists` again. Maybe your should flatten the list before vectorizing?

Answer (score 2):

`npes` is a list of lists and the `vectorizer` doesn't take list of lists as parameter. So flatten the list and send it as a parameter i.e

```
npes = [['a','b'], ['d','e'],['f','g']]
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
Xc = vectorizer.fit_transform(sum(npes, []))
```

If you are using numpy then `npes = np.ravel(npes)`